# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - PHP Docker with SSL through Nginx Proxy

Tags: php, docker, nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a environment set up with two PHP Docker and a Nginx Proxy. In theory the environment should be a dynamically-generated PHP resource platform which is operated by an API. When someone wants to generate an PHP resource for personal purposes the API does some SSH work and runs a new PHP docker, adds proxy configuration to Nginx and applies the config. The PHP docker have a internal Apache serwer using port 80, so SSL is added by the Nginx proxy.

The docker-compose.yml of the **first PHP docker** is as follows:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  php_resource_lecturer_1:
    container_name: php_resource_Lecturer_1
    build:
      context: /home/user/docker-composes/resources_php/templates/
    ports:
      - '9531:80'
    volumes:
      - /home/user/docker-composes/ftp/data/ftp/Lecturer_1/php/html/:/var/www/html
      
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: nginx_default
```

The second docker-compose.yml of the second PHP docker is identicall, only port and volume containing the PHP code changes:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  php_resource_student_2:
    container_name: php_resource_Student_2
    build:
      context: /home/user/docker-composes/resources_php/templates/
    ports:
      - '9532:80'
    volumes:
      - /home/user/docker-composes/ftp/data/ftp/Student_2/php/html/:/var/www/html
      
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: nginx_default
```

The Nginx Proxy config is as follows:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name php.example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
    
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name php.example.com; 
    server_tokens off;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/data.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/data.key;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location ~/lecturer1(.*)$ { 
        return 301 $scheme://php.example.com:9531$1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Connection          upgrade; # WebSocket support
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        allow   all;
        }

    location ~/student2(.*)$ {
        return 301 $scheme://php.example.com:9532$1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Connection          upgrade; # WebSocket support
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        allow   all;
        }

    }
```

So the problem is, when i set up the Nginx Proxy to work only through port 80 (HTTP) it just works as intended. But when i changed the configuration to support 443 (HTTPS) Nginx is in fact proxying correctly, but does not add SSL correctly. Below is a example what happens when you try opening the page (index.php) when using HTTPS:

[image: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when using presented configuration]

I just ran out of ideas by now. It was a chore to set up the location block proxy even, which is a must in this system, and now i ran into this breaking issue. I'm not sure if maybe the **301** is producing such response, but it needs to be like that, regular **proxy_pass** does not work when using proxying through different **location** blocks for me.

I would like to not set up the SSL inside the Docker/services, because it complicates the initial configuration and, for example, for Asp.Net docker (which the system also utilizes) it's a chore to set up. The system can be expanded to use different PHP/.Net docker images, for example PHP-FPM, PHP with composer, PHP Laravel, etc., so SSL configuration is preferred to be done by Nginx.

Comment: Based on what you write port 9531 is mapped to nginx port 80, i.e. where the plain HTTP config is. If you want to use HTTPS at port 9531 you need to map it to the port in nginx with HTTPS, i.e. 443 not 80.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Isn't this done by:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name php.example.com;

Comment: in your image you access port 9531. This is mapped in your config to port 80 of the server. Due do this it does not matter how port 443 is configured, since you don't access it.

Comment: The PHP docker use port 80 because they utilize internal Apache serwer hosting PHP on port 80. SSL is added a level above, by the proxy. I had multiple services set like this and it worked with similar nginx config and exposed docker port mapped to 80.

Comment: You directly access port 9531 in your screenshot, which is mapped to port 80 but not port 443 in nginx. This will work for plain HTTP but not HTTPS - which would need to be mapped to port 443